# Linq to Entities versus Linq to Objects Performance Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

In one of my applications, I'm trying to add the appointment "status" information in my view. I can do it without too much trouble and it doesn't slow the overall query down too much--except when I try to calculate one of the particular statuses.

Here is some additional background: the appointment's status has to be evaluated by examining a handful of fields. For the most part, it's not too bad, except when I need to calculate whether the patient was a "no-show" for their appointment.

In order to determine a no-show, I need to look at the `appt_date` field to see if it is before today's date. However, the appt_date is stored as a `VARCHAR` in the `yyyyMMdd` format. In order to compare it to today's date, I need to convert the `appt_date` value to a `Datetime` value.

However, in order to do that, it seems I need to switch from "Linq to Entites" to "Linq to Objects" by calling `AsEnumerable()` on the query (and making some other minor changes). Of course, then the problem is that the query becomes unacceptably slow. It's my understanding that the "Linq to Objects" approach slows things down because it's loading more data into memory so Entity Framework can generate the proper SQL query.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could overcome this problem and maintain good performance with the query? I would greatly appreciate any advice you can provide.

For reference, here is the query using Linq to Entites (and without the "no-show" calculation):

```
var referrals = 
               (from r in _context.Referrals
                join cu in _context.ClinicUsers on r.ClinicId equals cu.ClinicId
                from ppa in _context.ReferralPPAs
                            .Where(p => p.ref_id == r.seq_no.ToString())
                            .DefaultIfEmpty()
                from ap in _context.Appointments
                .Where(a => a.appt_id.ToString() == ppa.appt_id)
                .DefaultIfEmpty()
                join ec in _context.EnrolledClinics on r.ClinicId equals ec.ClinicId
                join pm in _context.ProviderMasters on ec.ClinicId equals pm.ClinicId
                join ml in _context.MasterLists on pm.HealthSystemGuid equals ml.Id
                join au in _context.Users on r.ApplicationUserId equals au.Id
                where cu.UserId == userId
                select new ReferralListViewModel()
                {
                    ClinicName = pm.Description,
                    ClinicId = r.ClinicId,
                    ReferralId = r.seq_no,
                    EnteredBy = (au.FirstName ?? string.Empty) + " " + (au.LastName ?? string.Empty),
                    PatientName = (r.LastName ?? string.Empty) + ", " + (r.FirstName ?? string.Empty),
                    DateEntered = r.create_timestamp,
                    AppointmentDate = ap != null ? ap.appt_date : string.Empty,
                    AppointmentTime = ap != null ? ap.begintime : string.Empty,
                    Status = ppa != null ? ppa.Status : string.Empty,
                    AppointmentStatus = (ap != null & ap.cancel_ind == "N" & ap.confirm_ind == "N" & ap.resched_ind == "N" & ap.appt_kept_ind == "N") ? "Scheduled" :
                                        (ap != null & ap.cancel_ind == "Y") ? "Cancelled" :
                                        (ap != null & ap.confirm_ind == "Y") ? "Confirmed" :
                                        (ap != null & ap.resched_ind == "Y") ? "Rescheduled" :
                                        (ap != null & ap.appt_kept_ind == "Y") ? "Kept" : string.Empty
                }).Distinct();
```

Using Linq to Objects works, but it is unacceptably slow:

```
var referrals = 
               (from r in _context.Referrals
                join cu in _context.ClinicUsers on r.ClinicId equals cu.ClinicId
                from ppa in _context.ReferralPPAs
                            .Where(p => p.ref_id == r.seq_no.ToString())
                            .DefaultIfEmpty()
                from ap in _context.Appointments
                .Where(a => a.appt_id.ToString() == ppa.appt_id)
                .DefaultIfEmpty()
                join ec in _context.EnrolledClinics on r.ClinicId equals ec.ClinicId
                join pm in _context.ProviderMasters on ec.ClinicId equals pm.ClinicId
                join ml in _context.MasterLists on pm.HealthSystemGuid equals ml.Id
                join au in _context.Users on r.ApplicationUserId equals au.Id
                where cu.UserId == userId
                select new { pm.Description, r.ClinicId, r.seq_no, au.FirstName, au.LastName, PatientLastName = r.LastName, PatientFirstName = r.FirstName, r.create_timestamp, ppa.Status, ap.cancel_ind, ap.confirm_ind, ap.resched_ind, ap.appt_kept_ind, ap.appt_date, ap.begintime })
                //Calling .AsEnumerable() converts it to Linq to Objects, which allows me to do the date conversion
                .AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(r => new ReferralListViewModel()
                    {
                        ClinicName = r.Description,
                        ClinicId = r.ClinicId,
                        ReferralId = r.seq_no,
                        EnteredBy = (r.FirstName ?? string.Empty) + " " + (r.LastName ?? string.Empty),
                        PatientName = (r.PatientLastName ?? string.Empty) + ", " + (r.PatientFirstName ?? string.Empty),
                        DateEntered = r.create_timestamp,
                        Status = r.Status != null ? r.Status : string.Empty,
                        AppointmentStatus = (r.cancel_ind != null & r.cancel_ind == "N" & r.confirm_ind == "N" & r.resched_ind == "N" & r.appt_kept_ind == "N") ? "Scheduled" :
                                            (r.cancel_ind != null & r.cancel_ind == "Y") ? "Cancelled" :
                                            (r.cancel_ind != null & r.confirm_ind == "Y") ? "Confirmed" :
                                            (r.cancel_ind != null & r.resched_ind == "Y") ? "Rescheduled" :
                                            //Here is the line used to calculate a "no-show" appointment
                                            (r.cancel_ind != null & r.appt_kept_ind == "N" & DateTime.ParseExact(r.appt_date, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) < today) ? "No-show" :
                                            (r.cancel_ind != null & r.appt_kept_ind == "Y") ? "Kept" : string.Empty
                    }).Distinct();
```

Comment: What about if you go with `Linq to Entites` but following change --- Create a child property of `AppointmentStatusType` (with internal accessor) which maps the required property like `cancel_ind` e.t.c. Then have `AppointmentStatus` as get only property which is being computed based on `AppointmentStatusType` object. Does this improve your performance?

Comment: I appreciate the idea, but Igor's answer below is going to require a lot less effort. Thank you for responding--I appreciate it!

Comment: both look terrible. post the sql, and then get someone to convert it properly.

Comment: @Seabizkit - Turns out that I can continue to use the first approach with the answer from Igor below.

Comment: "It's my understanding that the "Linq to Objects" approach slows things down because it's loading more data into memory so Entity Framework can generate the proper SQL query": No, it slows things down because it's pulling all the data into memory and *not generating a SQL query.* If you've got 200 `ReferralListViewModel`s and 2 distinct values, it calls `new ReferralListViewModel()` 200 times, sets the specified properties 200 times, and uses the default equality comparer to exclude 198 of them. LINQ to objects operates directly on the objects; the methods take delegates, not expression trees.

Comment: @phoog - Thank you for the clarification. I am not too old to learn! :-)

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad I managed to make enough sense despite cramming that all into 600 characters. Another benefit of understanding the difference between `System.Linq.Queryable` and `System.Linq.Enumerable` is that the reason for the "dreaded 'cannot be translated' error" becomes clear: with `S.L.Enumerable` there's no translation; you're just calling .NET code directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In order to determine a no-show, I need to look at the appt_date field to see if it is before today's date. However, the appt_date is stored as a VARCHAR in the yyyyMMdd format. In order to compare it to today's date, I need to convert the appt_date value to a Datetime value.
>
> Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could overcome this problem and maintain good performance with the query? I would greatly appreciate any advice you can provide.

Go the other direction, convert todays date to a varchar and use that in your comparison. This will allow you to use your existing indexes on the table as well.

```
var today = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd");

// in your query down below
string.Compare(r.appt_date, today) < 0 ? "No-show" : ....
```

See also [Canonical Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/canonical-functions) for what functions can be translated into store expressions by EF. As you had noticed `DateTime.ParseExact` is not one of them which is why you would be required to get the data into memory and then filter that in memory data again based on your condition. The sloweness comes from having to pull much more data than necessary from the database.

---

A better solution, but one which requires more work, is to change your schema and actually persist a DateTime as a Date or DateTime type. This is my recommendation but if you do not have control over the schema then it is not possible.

Comment: Dear @Igor, you are my hero! This is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much--I really appreciate your help! Also, you are right that it would be better to be able to change the schema, but in this case I do not have control over it. Again, thank you so much for the help--this is exactly what I needed and I already confirmed that it works. :-)

Comment: Going by the list of Canonical Functions, `String.Compare` isn't one of them??? Wouldn't just using `<=` be sufficient?

Comment: @NetMage - it is though as I have used it many times in the past, let me see where I can find it in the documentation...

Comment: @NetMage - I can't find it anywhere. It is supported but I will need some time to figure out where there is documentation that states it. I have had to use this from time to time for the exact same reason as the in the OP in querying a legacy DB where I had no control over the schema. I will look a little later and hit you up if I find anything.

Comment: NetMage - If you mean can you just do something like this: `ap.appt_date < today) ? "No-show"` then no, that doesn't work in this case. The compiler states that the '<' operator cannot be used to compare strings.

Comment: @BillKron Thanks, I use that so little I didn't realize C# had such a hole. I can imagine the extensions being created once extensions everywhere is available.

Comment: @Igor @BillKron BTW, shouldn't that be `< 0` not `< 1` for "before today's date"?

Comment: @BillKron / Netmage - Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally when using Entity Framework, all your operations should be doing Querable to allow parse tree evaluation at sql server level.
Your query is running slow not due to some underlying db reasons, but due to the fact that using Enumerable fetches the **entire** table into memory and then does the operations onto those.

If u do Querable, your entire expression will get converted into an sql query which runs on db and returns only matching records and once you have required data, on top of it feel free to apply Enumerable to suit your specific operations.

Try replacing and placing a profiler and see the generated query and how it runs, you will get to know the difference easily

Pseudo code below

```
Var query = from obj in db.AsQueryable()
```

Select obj.Name,........
Where obj.Id == myId

Query.AsEnumerable().where........

Comment: Yes, you're right to prefer IQueryable. The reason I had to switch over to IEnumerable was because of the dreaded "Method cannot be translated into a store expression" error. @Igor was able to help me understand how to get around the problem without going to IEnumerable. Thanks for responding--I really appreciate it!

Comment: How about moving everything into a stored procedure so all data stays in database without any transportation over the network?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The accepted answer by Igor is working well for me. Thanks again!